# "I am not able to catch NumberFormatException properly, because of this my onClick is not working

Tags: java, android, exception, encryption, casting

I was trying to build a simple app that takes the plain text and no of lines as input and convert the plain text into cipher text using the rail fence ciphering technique. I was taking no of lines input from user and convert that string input into integer by casting. As i was doing it, it shows `NumberFormatException`. I wrote the casting line inside the try block and there after the scope of that variable is limited such that my `encryption()` method is not able to access it. What can i do as my `onClick` function is not producing the correct desired cipher text?
The button behaves like it was never clicked.

I have tried creating that variable outside the `try` block and then typecasting it inside the block, i also made that `lines` variable `final` as it was accessed within the class. Then it asked me to initialize the variable, I have done that also but it does not seems helping me.

```
Button decryptBtn, encryptBtn;
TextView hlWrld, encryptedText;
EditText noOfLines, plainText;
int lines;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    decryptBtn = findViewById(R.id.decryptBtn);
    encryptBtn = findViewById(R.id.encrptBtn);
    hlWrld = findViewById(R.id.hlwWorld);
    encryptedText = findViewById(R.id.encryptedText);
    noOfLines = findViewById(R.id.lineNo);
    plainText = findViewById(R.id.plntxt);

    final String plntxt = plainText.getText().toString();
    final String noOflines = noOfLines.getText().toString();
    int lines = 0;
    try {
        lines = Integer.parseInt(noOflines);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    }

    final int finalLines = lines;

    encryptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            encryption(plntxt, finalLines);
        }
    });
}

public void encryption(String plntxt, int lines) {
    boolean checkdown = false;  // check whether it is moving downward or upward
    int j = 0;
    int row = lines;                  // no of row is the no of rails entered by user
    int col = plntxt.length();             //column length is the size of string
    char[][] a = new char[row][col];
    // we create a matrix of a of row *col size

    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {  // matrix visiting in rails order and putting the character of plaintext
        if (j == 0 || j == row - 1)
            checkdown = !checkdown;

        a[j][i] = plntxt.charAt(i);

        if (checkdown) {
            j++;
        } else {
            j--;
        }
    }

    // visiting the matrix in usual order to get ciphertext
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < col; k++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][k] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    String en = "";

    System.out.println("----------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < col; k++) {
            if (a[i][k] != 0)
                en = en + a[i][k];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(en); // printing the ciphertext
    encryptedText.setText(en);
}
```

I expect the output to be a cipher text come to me as a result of `setText()` method that I have applied on my `textView`. But, nothing is happening at all.

Comment: You are getting the values of plntxt and noOfLines in the onCreate() method, before the component has even been displayed, so the user has not had a chance to enter anything. Those values are probably empty strings, and thus parseInt() will fail, since an empty string is not a valid number format.

Comment: Please add your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was taking no of lines input from user and convert that string input into integer by casting. As i was doing it ,it shows NumberFormatException.

That is because you're trying to read a string from an EditText with no input yet as integer which is not a valid number with the following code (see the comment):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // your view binding code with findViewById
    // ...

    // here you're trying to read the EditText value,
    // but no user input yet because you've only inflate it before.
    final String plntxt= plainText.getText().toString();
    final String noOflines= noOfLines.getText().toString();
    // the noOfLines is "", an empty string.
    int lines = 0;
    try {
        // this raise an exception because empty string is not number.
        lines = Integer.parseInt(noOflines);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){

    }

    ...
}
```

> I have tried creating that variable outside the try block and then typecasting it inside the block, i also made that "lines" variable final as it was accessed within the class. then it ask me to initialize the variable, i have done that also but it does not seems helping me.

What you done is make more damage to your code because your making the variable value constant. Both the value of `plntxt` and `noOflines` will always be an `""`, empty string. So, your following code won't work:

```
final String plntxt= plainText.getText().toString();
final String noOflines= noOfLines.getText().toString();

...

final int finalLines = lines;
encryptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // this won't work because plntxt is always empty string
        // and finalLines is always invalid number.
        encryption(plntxt, finalLines);
    }
});
```

A simple fix can be done by moving all the text getter to the inside of your `onClick` method:

```
encryptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      String plntxt= plainText.getText().toString();
      String noOflines= noOfLines.getText().toString();
      int lines = 0;
      try {
        lines = Integer.parseInt(noOflines);
      }
       catch (NumberFormatException e){

      }

      encryption(plntxt, finalLines);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great that it help you :D